# Problems after import-spweb

Tags: powershell, diagnostics

I have used export-spweb and import-spweb to move multiple sites around in SP2010.

After import-spweb I notice that some libraries are really messed up. When I try to add an item to the announcements list I see 3, yes 3 save buttons! It seems that some guids somewhere mustn't be getting update and goodness knows how many inconsistencies there are across all the OOTB lists.

Is there a known issue around using import-spweb? More importantly is there any easy way I can diagnose/fix this issue?

Comment: I know one thing that occurs is that GUID do get mixed up and also workflow associations also. I had this issue before and I didn't post an answer because I can only offer advice based on my experience. Which was when i did that I had new list and document library ID's that I had to edit the Workflow XOML file to fix the workflows.

Comment: Thanks. Most of the components of this site were standard out-of-the-box lists etc but I've just no idea how to fix, other than create a new site and copy over the files.

Comment: Open SharePoint Designer and go into all files you can then see the xml files that configure the list. check the list guid ID and make sure it matches the one in the xml files.